# android dev: Services

Tags: android

i need to know that do i define the service class as a seperate .class file or do i define it within my main class of the activity ?

can someone provide me with an example apart from this one... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

???
:/
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using Services from the docs. In this case for Bluetooth. It should give you enough of an idea of how to construct your own.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/index.html

Comment: can you please tell me if i can create a service class within my main class or do i need seperate class file ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should create a separate class for your service, which you'll start through your Main Activity.

Here a quick tutorial: http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/android-simple-service/